# Checking if SCTP clients disconnected from SCTP endpoint

Tags: linux, networking

I want to properly check if an SCTP client disconnected and I want to enable SCTP_STATUS for an SCTP endpoint (i.e. SOCK_SEQPACKET), but I don't seem to be able to set that. It's explained here https://linux.die.net/man/7/sctp
That means my function call looks like this:

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SCTP, SCTP_STATUS, &1, sizeof(int))
```

When calling it, I get "Protocol not found" (code: 92), even though it is supported on my system, as I can flawlessly send and receive SCTP packets.

What causes this behaviour? Is there another option to check the client's connection status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you're trying to use is not a boolean to activate a feature (like you would for `SO_REUSEADDR`). it's a *read-only* full featured `struct sctp_status` as defined in [RFC6458](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6458#section-8.2.1):

> ```
> 8.2.  Read-Only Options
>
>    The options defined in this subsection are read-only.  Using this
>    option in a setsockopt() call will result in an error indicating
>    EOPNOTSUPP.
>
> 8.2.1.  Association Status (SCTP_STATUS)
>
>    Applications can retrieve current status information about an
>    association, including association state, peer receiver window size,
>    number of unacknowledged DATA chunks, and number of DATA chunks
>    pending receipt.  This information is read-only.
>
>    The following structure is used to access this information:
>
>    struct sctp_status {
> ```

[...]

So to solve your problem: remove entirely this `setsockopt()` call.

You should be using `getsockopt()` appropriately.

Some examples:
SO: [SCTP Multihoming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342617/sctp-multihoming)

> ```
> i = sizeof(status);
>     if((ret = getsockopt(sock, SOL_SCTP, SCTP_STATUS, &status, (socklen_t *)&i)) != 0)
>         perror("getsockopt");
>
>     printf("\nSCTP Status:\n--------\n");
>     printf("assoc id  = %d\n", status.sstat_assoc_id);
>     printf("state     = %d\n", status.sstat_state);
>     printf("instrms   = %d\n", status.sstat_instrms);
>     printf("outstrms  = %d\n--------\n\n", status.sstat_outstrms);
> ```

[SCTP server client Code in C](https://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2011/11/basic-sctp-client-server-code-in-c.html)

> ```
>    //check status
>    opt_len = (socklen_t) sizeof(struct sctp_status);
>    getsockopt(SctpScocket, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_STATUS, &status, &opt_len);
> ```

Comment: thanks for the answer - Ill try that and report my results later.

Comment: directly in C it seems to be working but Im trying to use it in Rust and get code 22, "Invalid argument" - what could cause this? I can send information if you are interested

Comment: I'm sorry: I think I addressed your issue. The rest is really about programming. I didn't know this was rust (I admit the use of `&1` looked a bit strange). You should ask a programming question on SO instead. But just in case: please note how **opt_len** is passed by reference, not by value.

Comment: thats done through the wrapper function automatically - but thank you anyway

Comment: ok Ive done it like in the example but getsockopt() returns -1 - Do you have an idea? - I can send an strace if you desire.